# window.location.reload(true) reloads page but page needs refreshing to show changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Have a function that makes a change to taxonomy term via AJAX. This works great, except the content remains unchanged on `window.location.reload(true)` even though the change has been made. See the code and GIF below to understand.

This is an example that adds the button and reloads page on click

```
if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status && $post->post_type === 'campaigns' ) {
$text = (in_category( 'live') ? 'Activate' : 'Activate');
echo '<li><a href="" onclick="window.location.reload(true);return toggleLive(this, ' . $post->ID . ');">' . $text . '</a></li>';
}
```

[image: explainer gif]

So, is there another way that I can reload the page `onClick` that may help? Also, the post modified date is not updating, yet changes have been made to the post.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT - 
I have already tried
`location.href = location.href;` and
`document.location.reload();`

ADDITIONAL INFO -

Function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_toggle_live', function(){
// Check ID is specified
if ( empty($_REQUEST['post']) ) {
    die( __('No post ID specified.') );
}

// Load post
$post_id = (int) $_REQUEST['post'];
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) {
    die( __('You attempted to edit an item that doesn&amp;#8217;t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?') );
}

// Check permissions
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
if ( !current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->edit_post, $post_id) ) {
    die( __('You are not allowed to edit this item.') );
}

// Load current categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'campaign_action', array('fields' => 'ids'));

// Add/remove Starred category
$live = get_term_by( 'live', 'campaign_action' );

$index = array_search($live, $terms);
if ($_REQUEST['value']) {
    if ($index === false) {
        $terms[] = $live;
    }
} else {
    if ($index !== false) {
        unset($terms[$index]);
    }
}

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'live', 'campaign_action' );

die('1');
});
```

JS

```
function toggleLive(caller, post_id)
{

var $ = jQuery;
var $caller = $(caller);

var waitText = ". . .";
var liveText = ". . .";
var deactivateText = ". . .";

// Check there's no request in progress
if ($caller.text() == waitText) {
    return false;
}

// Get the new value to set to
var value = ($caller.text() == liveText ? 1 : 0);

// Change the text to indicate waiting, without changing the width of the button
$caller.width($caller.width()).text(waitText);

// Ajax request
var data = {
    action: "toggle_live",
    post:   post_id,
    value:  value
};

jQuery.post("<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response)
{
    if (response == "1") {

        // Success
        if (value) {
            $caller.text(deactivateText);
        } else {
            $caller.text(liveText);
        }

    } else {

        // Error
        alert("Error: " + response);

        // Reset the text
        if (value) {
            $caller.text(deactivateText);
        } else {
            $caller.text(liveText);
        }

    }

    // Reset the width
    $caller.width("auto");
});

// Prevent the link click happening
return false;
}
```

IT WORKS RIGHT ON PAGE THAT ISN'T SINGULAR
[image]

Comment: why don't you try `document.location.reload()`?

Comment: Thank you @NaveenKumarSangi. I have tried that already and the outcome was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is toggleLive the function that makes the AJAX request? You are calling reload immediately on click before changes are reflected on the backend. If you are using Jquery include your reload code in the complete callback function that indicates completion of your AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you @cdoshi. I have updated the question with both the JS and function included. Would you be able to suggest where I could include the reload code? Appreciate your help.

Comment: When you call Jquery.post, the callback function is executed on success of your request. Include the reload inside the callback function and also remove reload which is triggered onclick

Comment: I am not sure that this is the issue now. I added `location.reload(true);` to the function success callback. Didn't make a difference. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, make sure to remove the reload from echo '<li><a href="" onclick="window.location.reload(true);return toggleLive(this, ' . $post->ID . ');">' . $text . '</a></li>';

Also, make sure that the callback is triggered by setting a breakpoint inside the callback

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I also added to another page that isn't `singular` and it works as intended. GIF showed in updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Live Query plug-in in jquery instead of live .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Looks interesting so will be giving it a read.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by setting `return trueOrFalse(bool);` in the JS and adding the permalink for the page into `<a href="">` within the function.

I believe @cdoshi was correct in their answer, yet I was unable to achieve this. I am sure that a little further exploration would make this possible, yet my fix achieved what I wanted with little change to my code.

Comment: Glad to hear it!!